# python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully - when installing magenta

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmake, magenta, llvmlite

I am facing an issue while installing the "magenta" package in my python 3.9.12 architecture while using the command `pip install magenta`.

It retrieves an error when getting to the point

```
Building wheels for collected packages: llvmlite
  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2h8aaubh
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ...   Destination directory: C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2h8aaubh
  Running command python setup.py bdist_wheel
  running bdist_wheel
  C:\Users\ricar\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9fq4zbfc\llvmlite_66cdc9c78f06483abf4ae29b277713c0\ffi\build.py
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19044.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
    Failed to run MSBuild command:

      MSBuild.exe

    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

      Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/ricar/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp0f_7kimx/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/ricar/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp1bsukddp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Trying generator 'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64'
  Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9fq4zbfc\llvmlite_66cdc9c78f06483abf4ae29b277713c0\ffi\build.py", line 192, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9fq4zbfc\llvmlite_66cdc9c78f06483abf4ae29b277713c0\ffi\build.py", line 180, in main
      main_win32()
    File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9fq4zbfc\llvmlite_66cdc9c78f06483abf4ae29b277713c0\ffi\build.py", line 89, in main_win32
      generator = find_win32_generator()
    File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9fq4zbfc\llvmlite_66cdc9c78f06483abf4ae29b277713c0\ffi\build.py", line 85, in find_win32_generator
      raise RuntimeError("No compatible cmake generator installed on this machine")
  RuntimeError: No compatible cmake generator installed on this machine
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\ricar\\anaconda3\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
```

I've tried to check the compatibility of the llvm lite package 0.38.1 to the numba version 0.55.1. Further I've tried to check the latest "cmake" package.

I have no other clues right now and would appreciate if anyone got a solution for that or faced a similar problem.

Comment: Read the error messages: " could not find any instance of Visual Studio." you need to install visual studio.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that hint. I installed Visual Studio now. 
No changes on that. 
Is it possible that there is some issue with the MSBuild.exe which cant be executed ?
thanks